# Adversarially Robust Googlenet model

Tags: tensorflow, cleverhans

How train a googlenet model adversarially on an own image classification dataset?

For example: Using cleverhans library, the data that has batches to run the attacks on are MNIST and CIFAR.

I trained an image classifier with my own data (Googlenet) using Tensorflow, now I want to train the model with the adversarial examples. Any ideas that I can do with the cleverhans library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is probably to start from your own code to train GoogleNet and modify its loss. You can find an example modification of the loss that adds a penalty to train on adversarial examples in the [CleverHans tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans_tutorials/mnist_tutorial_tf.py#L160). It uses the loss implementation [found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans/loss.py#L116) to define a weighted average between the cross-entropy on clean images and the cross-entropy on adversarial images.